# Combining multiple image in to single file

Tags: java, image, hadoop

To convert all images in a folder to a single file , i used \n as delimiter to separate images in that file. is this is good enough?. (If the image bytes contain \n bytes then it will become an issue while processing), is there any chance that an image file may contain \n's equivalent byte inside it.

Comment: And how does this suppose to work? If you open it in image viewer it should display one image attached to the bottom of another ?

Comment: No , the newly created file is a simple file without any extension , The purpose is to process the image file in map-reduce. I have done the map-reduce part by keeping delimiter as \n and processed the image (Face detection using open CV)

Comment: sounds like bad approach :(

Comment: Can you suggest any good approach :)

Comment: What is wrong with processing array of image files?

Comment: Is this  what you mean . File[] imageArray=new File[n] ?,
The image files are in a directory in HDFS

Comment: But to "combine" them you first need to read them anyway. So why not process it @ that time insteed of additional work ?

Comment: Map-reduce is using to achieve parallel programming. Creating a new file is not a good approach , but this is required since , if I keep all raw images in to HDFS and then if I let map-reduce to process those images, it will result in spawning of many map-tasks(One for each file). Creating all images into single file help me to avoid this drawback, also map-reduce will split this file in to many logical splits and can process it in parallel.

Comment: it is typical XY problem - you want to do X but you are asking about Y. Ask new question and include what you want to achieve. Dont forget to mention that you want to use Hadoop and Hadoop MapReduce.

Comment: I planed not introduce mapreduce into this question. The question can be simple as this ,

is there any chance that \n 's  or #'s or $'s equivalent byte will present in an image file. if not I can use any of these character as delimiter if I combine multiple images into a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both images to byte arrays and then using base64 encoder, convert each byte array to string. Then you can use `\n` as delimiter between these two images.

To get the images back as byte arrays, you should decode those strings in the file using base64 decoder. I think almost all languages support Base64 encoding and decoding.